# What is the best way to create a database and tables from the same file?

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, mysql-connector-python

I have the following code:

```
import mysql.connector as msqltor
import os
db = msqltor.connect(
    host='localhost',
    user='root',
    passwd=os.environ.get('DB_PASSWD'),
    database='The_Ride'
)

my_cursor = db.cursor()

Q1 = "CREATE DATABASE The_Ride"


Q2 = '''CREATE TABLE users(
        userID int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        username VARCHAR(25), 
        password VARCHAR(25),  
        PRIMARY KEY (userID)
        )'''

Q3 = '''CREATE TABLE bookings(
        booking_id int UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, 
        userID int UNSIGNED, 
        another_column VARCHAR(25),
        PRIMARY KEY (booking_id),
        FOREIGN KEY (userID) REFERENCES users(userID)
        )'''

Q4 = '''ALTER TABLE users AUTO_INCREMENT=1001'''

Q5 = '''ALTER TABLE bookings AUTO_INCREMENT=1111'''

my_cursor.execute(Q1)

#query_dict = [Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
#for i in query_dict:
#    my_cursor.execute(i)
```

Using `Q1` I will create the database, but I usually, just input some other database while defining `db`.
After that I comment out `my_cursor.execute(Q1)`, and un-comment the rest. And then run the file again. While this method works, I want to do this by running the file only once.

Comment: `I want to do this by running the file only once.` - You have specified your requirement, do you have a question? Are you stuck somewhere in implementation? Welcome to SO. This isn't a discussion forum or tutorial. Please take the [tour] and take the time to read [ask] and the other links found on that page.

Comment: Does the `for` loop at the bottom of your code not work?

Comment: @Bert The `for` loop won't work if I don't create the database `The_Ride` first.

Comment: @wwii I asked the question at the top, right? If that is against the rules, I will make sure to follow the rules next time on.

Answer (score 0):

I've faced this problem before. This cannot be solved using the Python's pymysql or MySQLdb library, Because of Block Statements like functions and procedures cannot be parsed.

So a Single Sourcing of file is not possible. *(Unless you're willing to build a parser With MySQL Parsing from scratch)*

The only solution is to Leverage on **DELIMITER** command.

Anyways here's what I did this.

```
def parse_sql(query_file_string_):
    stmts = list()
    delim = ';'
    stmt=''
    for lineno, line in enumerate(string_.split('\n')):

        if not line.strip():
            continue

        if line.startswith('--'):
            continue

        if re.match('DELIMITER', line, re.I):
            delim = line.split()[1]
            continue

        if delim not in line:
            stmt += re.sub('DELIMITER', ';', line, re.I)
            continue

        if stmt:
            stmt += line
            stmt = stmt.replace(delim, '')
            stmts.append(" " + stmt.strip() + " ")
            stmt = ''
        else:
            line = line.replace(delim, '')
            stmts.append(" " + line.strip() + " ")
    return stmts
```

Just run your sourcing commands one by one after this and **commit**. This should allow you to perform this.

~~ Hope this helps and Happy Coding ~~

Answer (score 0):

You need to commit your transactions.

```
query_dict = [Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5]
for i in query_dict:
    my_cursor.execute(i)
    my_cursor.commit()
```

From the MySQL connector documentation:

> This method sends a COMMIT statement to the MySQL server, committing
> the current transaction. Since by default Connector/Python does not
> autocommit, it is important to call this method after every
> transaction that modifies data for tables that use transactional
> storage engines.